# How can split string not include first character?

Tags: c#

i have some text and `split` by `"-"` but i don't want `split` first character:
EX:

```
"1-2" => [1,2]
"-1-2" => [-1,2]
"1-2-3" => [1,2,3]
"-1-2-3" => [-1,2,3]
```

If i use this code, it will all :

```
strValue.Split("-");
```

How can split string not include first character?

Comment: Check if first character is -, if true then take a substring and split it else split the whole string

Comment: what is the string for `[-1,-2,3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to split on '-' and if the first entry in the array is empty, then assume that the second entry is a negative number

```
var x = input.Split('-');
IEnumerable<string> y = x;
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x[0])){
  x[1] = "-"+x[1];
  y= x.Skip(1);
}
var z = y.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Or flip it after:

```
var z = input.Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

if(input[0] == '-')
  z[0] *= -1;
```

Comment: thank you, it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is very simple, and without number conversion. Since, in case you have something like **"-a-b", it does not convert to a number**.
And the question says about characters in some text.

```
    string[] list;
    if (str.StartsWith("-")) {
        list = str.Substring(1).Split('-');
        list[0]= "-" + list[0];
    } else {
        list = str.Split('-');
    }
```

Here is a C# Fiddle to play with: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C2qERs

Comment: thank you, it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string[] Spliting(string toSplit) 
        {
            string[] result=null;

            if (toSplit[0].Equals('-')) 
            {
                result = (toSplit.Substring(1)).Split("-");
                result[0] = "-" + result[0];
            }
            else 
            {
                result = toSplit.Split("-");
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: thank you, it is ok.

Comment: You don't need the extra parentheses here  `result = toSplit.Substring(1).Split("-");`

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "-1-2-3";
int[] result = input.Substring(1).Split('-').Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); 
if(input[0] == '-')
    result[0] *= -1;
```